# Pages being cached and i don't know why?

Tags: php, html

Pages being cached wno matter what i tried.
As a result php functions run once and after that show the cached result always until you hit Shift+F5

1. I disabled Opcache (no opcache anymore on phpinfo())
2. I disabled APC (no APC anymore on phpinfo())
3. I used headers

   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
   header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
   header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
   header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
   header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
4. I added at apache2/000-default-conf

   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public"
5. I added at .htaccess

   RewriteEngine On
   <FilesMatch ".(html|htm|js|css)$">
   FileETag None

   Header unset ETag
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
   Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"

No more solutions come to mind.

Anyone happens to know what is going on?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: which browser? or is this in all browsers? What are the headers that are sent on request and received from the server?

Comment: Are you by any chance connected to any virtual caching, either through the hosting provider or other third parties?

Comment: It happens to be being cached by service worker.. Many thanks for your time guys

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code should make cache expire immediately in PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

header("Expires: 0");
or use:
header("Expires: on, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"); //--> for old browsers

header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```